# Adding an RSS image feed from instagram into website

Tags: jquery, html, css, rss, instagram

I am trying to add the most recent image from an Instagram feed into a web page, and was wondering if it would be possible to do it within a div as you would place any other element on the page.

I would like to resize each image to 280 x 280 and would like to display only the image - no text or hashtags.

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do this but I found you could pull the RSS feed from statigram for example http://statigr.am/feed/username

And realising I would need to display the image in full and adjust the height I found this page on RSS image: http://www.w3schools.com/rss/rss_tag_image.asp

Does anyone know the best way for me to do this?

Answer (score 7):

I haven't tried it but this looks like it will do what you want: http://stuffthatspins.com/2012/03/30/display-instagram-picture-stream-really-easy-with-jquery-and-json/

You won't get javascript to truly resize the images AFAIK, but you can set up css to constrain the way they are displayed. For example if all the images had the class instagram:

```
img.instagram{width:280px; height:280px;}
```

Comment: No problem! if it works for you consider accepting this answer, that way everyone knows it works and it may be more helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to code it yourself, then the best way to get the feed would be to use the Instagram Media API -
https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_media_recent

You will get a JSON feed and will need to display style the results yourself.

OR you can save yourself all that time and use a fully coded plugin that will pull in the feed from Instagram. One good example would be to try the InstaMax plugin. With Instamax, you can display photos and videos from any User Account or HashTag. (pretty much what you want)

Cheers :)